# line в line безье

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как можно обычный line изогнуть так, чтобы получить кривую безье с началом в точке (x1, y1) и концом в точке (x2, y2).

Если что, то мне необходимо чтобы она создавалась динамически.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ой, кривая, перепутал, думал одно и тоже ))

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вам нужен график. Рекомендую изучить библиотеку oxyplot

Comment: Да не, у меня всё уже есть и line и такие же модули, но line у меня просто прямой а я хотел чтобы он был изогнутый.